# How do I insert a row when two or more consecutive rows in a column are the same?

Tags: vba, excel

I apologize for all the text, but this is a little complex and I wish to avoid confusion:

I need code that will insert one empty row when two consecutive cells in a column are the not the same (e.g., If H2 <> H3, then insert an empty row beneath row 2). However, it must also be able to insert two empty rows when any two *or more* consecutive cells in a column are the same (e.g., If H4 = H5, then insert two empty rows beneath H5, or if H4 = H5 = H6, then insert two empty rows beneath H6.)

The point is to have one empty row separating all data-containing rows in which the value in column H is not the same, and to have two rows beneath groups of rows in which the value in column H is the same. That leaves an extra empty row beneath the group so the extra empty row can contain a sum of the group's values in column P.

I have figured out how to do the first task with this code:

```
Sub SepFcpDs()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Integer
'Search code
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Dim i As Long
'Begin loop code
For i = 2 To LastRow

'Insert an empty row if FcpDs do not match
If (Range("H" & i) <> Range("H" & i).Offset(1)) And Not IsEmpty(Range("H" & i)) Then

        Range("H" & i).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

End If

Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'End loop code
End Sub
```

I cannot figure out how to make it find groups of rows, which may be of any size, in which groups of rows in column H are the same, and then to insert an extra row beneath these groups. I have tried modifying the code above as such:

```
If (Range("I" & i) = Range("I" & i).Offset(-1)) _ 
    And (Range("I" & i) = Range("I" & i).Offset(-2)) And Not IsEmpty(Range("I" & i)) Then

    Range("I" & i).EntireRow.Insert

End If
```

This code does not work (returns Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error). How do I fix this?

Comment: Quick comment:  when you are adding rows, your loop is no longer going to get to the end of your data.  If the lastrow is initially row 100 and you add a row in the middle, then your lastrow is now 101, but your loop is going to stop at 100....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick.

```
Sub SepFcpDs()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastRowWithValue As Integer
Dim Column As String
ColToSearch = "H"
'Search code
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, ColToSearch).End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long
'Begin loop code
LastRowWithValue = LastRow
For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
    'Insert an empty row if FcpDs do not match
    If (Range(ColToSearch & i) <> Range(ColToSearch & i).Offset(-1)) Then
        If i <> LastRowWithValue Then
            Range(ColToSearch & (LastRowWithValue + 1)).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
        Range(ColToSearch & i).EntireRow.Insert
        LastRowWithValue = i - 1
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'End loop code
```

EDIT: Updated to work even if there are multiple groupings of the same value in the column.  This won't deal with the next column if you have different requirements, but should at least be a start.

Comment: This works well. Thank you! I have it run on column H, then have itrun on column I to "sort" again, then run a cleanup sub to remove any extra rows. However, some values in column H (and I) do appear more than once, and not always together, when the corresponding values in Column I differ. For example, I might have H2=016 & I2=258, H3=016 & I3=258, H4=017 & I4=258, but then further down, I might have H15=016 again, but this time I15=555. As you expected, it does not seem to work correctly in these cases.

Comment: Did not work properly until I moved `LastRowWithValue = i - 1` up above `If i <> LastRowWithValue Then`, I guess because it was trying and failing to execute the `i <> LastRowWithValue` if-then statement without having `LastRowWithValue` defined. At any rate, it seems to work with that change. Thanks again!

Comment: Ahhh, I think you just want to initialize it to something before all of the loops instead of moving it entirely....I think it might mess things up if you just move it....See above edit.

Comment: The most recent edit seems to work without any need for modification. Thanks again!

Comment: Scratch that, sorry - the most recent edit does not work quite correctly. It fails to insert a second empty row under duplicates that occur in rows 2 and 3, and when `For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1` is adjusted to `For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1` it inserts an empty row under the header row. That is ok, though. My cleanup sub can take care of it. Thanks again!

Comment: I think if you try the proposed changes, it will work properly, but I may be mistaken.